# Dependencies error 1 not solivng problem google_maps

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies

I'm trying to upgrade all the dependencies, but this error is still shown. I have tried to override them but shows a no privileges error. I already tried to run `flutter pub cache repair`, `flutter pub get`, and not sure if I need to delete the cache or maybe reinstall flutter in another file, please any suggest could help.

```
Because google_map_polyline >=0.0.4 <0.2.0 depends on google_maps_flutter ^0.5.21+4 and google_map_polyline <0.0.4 depends on google_maps_flutter ^0.5.19+2, google_map_polyline <0.2.0 requires google_maps_flutter ^0.5.19+2.
And because google_map_polyline >=0.2.0 depends on google_maps_flutter ^0.5.21+6, every version of google_map_polyline requires google_maps_flutter ^0.5.19+2.
So, because fletgo_user_app depends on both google_maps_flutter ^2.1.0 and google_map_polyline any, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fletgo_user_app depends on both google_maps_flutter ^2.1.0 and google_map_polyline any, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because google_map_polyline is set to 'any'. But the real problem appear because [google_map_polyline](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyline) is already **discontinued**.

I suggest you change the library and migrate using the [flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points)

Comment: Thank you ill try that then, and also im trying to add conekta as my bridge in my app by using flutter, but im kinda confuse, can you help me or suggest an easy way to do it? Appreciate it!

Comment: I've never used conekta, not yet. Please mark this as an accepted answer if this is resolved your issue :)